# Easiest way to check for file extension in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, gzip

I have a shell script where I need to do one command if a file is zipped (ends in .gz) and another if it is not. I'm not really sure how to approach this, here's an outline of what I'm looking for:

```
file=/path/name*

if [ CHECK FOR .gz ]
then echo "this file is zipped"
else echo "this file is not zipped"
fi
```

Comment: `zip != gzip`, that should be "this file is (not) gzipped"

Comment: The *proper* way would be to use file.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can do this with a simple regex, using the `=~` operator inside a `[[...]]` test:

```
if [[ $file =~ \.gz$ ]];
```

This won't give you the right answer if the extension is `.tgz`, if you care about that. But it's easy to fix:

```
if [[ $file =~ \.t?gz$ ]];
```

The absence of quotes around the regex is necessary and important. You could quote `$file` but there is no point.

It would probably be better to use the `file` utility:

```
$ file --mime-type something.gz
something.gz: application/x-gzip
```

Something like:

```
if file --mime-type "$file" | grep -q gzip$; then
  echo "$file is gzipped"
else
  echo "$file is not gzipped"
fi
```

Comment: In `bash`, you can also use `if [[ $file = *.gz ]]` in place of regular expression matching.

Comment: @chepner, true enough but I wanted to provide the pattern which matches either `.gz` or `.tgz`. Admittedly, yours is a bit shorter. I think the `file` solution is the better choice, though.

Answer (score 37):

Really, the clearest and often easiest way to match patterns like this in a shell script is with `case`

```
case "$f" in
*.gz | *.tgz ) 
        # it's gzipped
        ;;
*)
        # it's not
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Yes you are right. This is the cleanest IMHO.

Comment: I like this one the best, actually. It is cleanest by far.

Answer (score 14):

You can try something like this:-

```
if [[ ${file: -3} == ".gz" ]]
```

Comment: You should use `[[` or quote `${file: -3}`; otherwise it will break if `$file` has a space as it's second last character, or (possibly) contains a glob metacharacter in the last three characters.

Comment: @rici:-Thanx for the suggestion. Updated my answer as well!! :)

Comment: You can also use `${file##*.} = gz`, which will work in any POSIX-compliant shell.

Comment: @chepner: Unless the filename is "gz" in which case you'll get a (probably) false positive. (And you should quote the expansion in case the filename has a space in it.)

Comment: Word splitting doesn't occur for expanded parameters in a `[[ ... ]]` conditional expression, but you are right about the false positive for files named `gz`.

Comment: Heh.  [ -z "${file##*.gz}" ]

Comment: Is my answer wrong?????

Comment: Actually I am asking this as it has worked for me in the past. So wanted to know if I am wrong somewhere?? ;-)

Comment: @chepner: `[[` is not required by Posix; since you said "will work in any POSIX-compliant shell", I assumed you meant with `[`

Comment: @RahulTripathi: No, it's fine. This is just an exploration of alternatives. Since the wrong answer was accepted, we might as well have our fun here. :)

Comment: @rici: oh, right. No point in restricting yourself to POSIX parameter expansion inside a `[[ ... ]]` expression :)

Comment: This really is sad when you don't get upvoted for right answers and a wrong one is accepted...;-)

Comment: It isn't that it's wrong for the question as asked, it's that people who need to ask for this are then very confused when their `#!/bin/sh` scripts fail.

Comment: I wanted to point out that the space after the colon is important. `${var:-3}` is not the same as `${var: -3}`; the first (without a space) will expand as '-3' if var is unset the second (with a space) returns the last 3 characters of var.